# Asterisk,SIP Retransmission timeout

Tags: sip, asterisk

I have created a sip trunk from One Asterisk(version 11.2.1) say 'A' server to another Asterisk server(11.7.0) say 'B', and I am getting sip response 200 ok.
But when I start calling on a DID on  Asterisk A then the call is being routed to Asterisk 'B' and After 38 seconds call has been disconnected showing following warnings :

```
Retransmission timeout reached on transmission 11bc71e029119e5877806ed40fcde691@111.xxx.xxx.xxx:5060 for seqno 102 (Critical Response) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 32000ms with no response
Hanging up call 11bc71e029119e5877806ed40fcde691@111.xxx.xxx.xx:5060 - no reply to our critical packet (see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions).
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: can you call the DDI on your server 'A' without the trunk (A-B)  configuation? To make sure your dialplan is correct.

Comment: Yes, Its working perfectly without trunk configuration. The main issue is call is being disconnected after 38 seconds, Before 38 seconds I can listen audio files to, As soon as the call reaches to 38th seconds , I t dropped

Comment: so...have you solved your problem yet?

Comment: Yes, As I mentioned it below it was due to nat setting in sip.conf

Comment: please tag it as solved ;) thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such situation can be spot when you have nat issues or firewall issue

See this article
  http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions

For more info you can enable sip debug by using

```
 asterisk -r
 sip set debug on
```

Comment: I have removed the firewall settings, This issue is not related firewall, For Nat I have used nat=force_rport,comedia in sip.conf.

Comment: From debug log, Asterisk server 'B' keeps on showing Retransmitting #{1-9}(NAT), where {1-9} showing retransmition attempt,

Comment: Retransmitting #3 (NAT) to 111.XXX.XXX.X:5060:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 111.XXX.XXX.X:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5e38e44b;received=111.XXX.XXX.X;rport=5060
From: <sip:07428239333@111.XXX.XXX.X>;tag=as086c55da
To: <sip:6603XXXX@175.XXX.XXX.X>;tag=as36de7a5b
Call-ID: 72cd617b6e36fd187315d5fd5d892e5d@111.XXX.XXX.X:5060
CSeq: 102 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.7.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uas
Contact: <sip:6603XXXX@10.XXX.XXX.X:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp

Comment: So you have nat or firewall issues like i say.

Comment: Thanks for your reaponse, please suggest me the solution to overcome this problem

Comment: Setup nat/fix firewall.

Answer (score 10):

By default Asterisk sends a RE-INVITE request after a call is established.

But most sip clients and sip servers in the market do not accept RE-INVITE requests. For this reason, when Asterisk sends a RE-INVITE after a call is established, the other side does not answer the request. So, after 32 seconds, Asterisk hangs up the call.

To solve the problem, you need to disable the RE-INVITE feature of Asterisk if your client software does not accept RE-INVITE requests. To do this, you need to edit the `sip.conf` file in Asterisk to include:

```
canreinvite = no
```

Answer (score 2):

These incidents usually associated with NAT problems.

If you're sure that this isn't your problem, take a look at router configuration. Some routers are configured by default with "SIP ALG" option.

In some cases, this option should be off because implementation is incomplete.

Try it, and let me known if it works properly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I figured it out earlier, It was due to NAT settings. I had resolved this issue.

Comment: @Vivek How can you solved this problem with Nat ? What specific nat do you mean ??

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have correct ip address in 'externip=' in sip.conf under /etc/asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like nat problems.
Can you share your sip configs so we can take a look?

Have you set your extenip and localip?