# Asterisk dialplan - waitexten hangs up immediately and does not wait

Tags: asterisk

Consider the following asterisk dialplan. After the last sound file is played it hangs up immediately and the waitexten timeout parameter seems to be ignored. The behaviour I am trying to achieve is to wait a given number of seconds after the last sound file is completed to get a response and then hang up. The last sound file says "Dial * to hear these options again". If I set the waitexten timeout to say 60, it hangs up before the sound files are played. A shorter time allows them all to be played but then it hangs up immediately. Any suggestions for handling this a better way are welcome

```
[mainmenu]
exten => s,1,Wait(0.25)
  same => 2,Answer()
  same => 3,Background(/srv/asterisk/sounds/optionslist)
  same => n,Background(/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial2cs)
  same => n,Background(/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial3ma)
  same => n,Background(/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial4ac)
  same => n,Background(/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial0)
  same => n,Background(/srv/asterisk/sounds/dialstar)
  same => n,WaitExten(20)
exten => 2,1,Goto(cs,2,1)
exten => *,1,Goto(s,3)
```

console output

```
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [+12345@public:1] Goto("SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044", "mainmenu,s,1") in new stack
    -- Goto (mainmenu,s,1)
    -- Executing [s@mainmenu:1] Wait("SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044", "0.25") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@mainmenu:4] BackGround("SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044", "/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial2cs") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@mainmenu:5] BackGround("SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044", "/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial3ma") in new stack
    -- <SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044> Playing '/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial3ma.slin' (language 'en')
    -- Executing [s@mainmenu:6] BackGround("SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044", "/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial4ac") in new stack
    -- <SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044> Playing '/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial4ac.slin' (language 'en')
    -- Executing [s@mainmenu:7] BackGround("SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044", "/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial0") in new stack
    -- <SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044> Playing '/srv/asterisk/sounds/dial0.slin' (language 'en')
    -- Executing [s@mainmenu:8] BackGround("SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044", "/srv/asterisk/sounds/dialstar") in new stack
    -- <SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044> Playing '/srv/asterisk/sounds/dialstar.slin' (language 'en')
[
[Aug  4 05:03:28] WARNING[2225]: chan_sip.c:4175 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission xxx@0.0.0.0 for seqno 5305 (Critical Response) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 32001ms with no response
[Aug  4 05:03:28] WARNING[2225]: chan_sip.c:4204 retrans_pkt: Hanging up call xxx@0.0.0.0 - no reply to our critical packet (see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions).
  == Spawn extension (mainmenu, s, 8) exited non-zero on 'SIP/xxx.pstn.twilio.com-00000044'
```

Asterisk 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1

Comment: Show your verbose logs of execution **mainmenu** context, please.

Comment: Edited question to include console output.

Comment: Try to replace first `Background` with `Playback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have a problem like in this topic [Asterisk,SIP Retransmission timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093328/asterisk-sip-retransmission-timeout). Try to solve the problem with the NAT settings or firewall.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30058658/1489324) propose to set `canreinvite=no` in `sip.conf`.

Comment: How can I fix NAT, the call is coming from twilio and the asterisk server is on an AWS vps?

Comment: I cannot help you in this situation. Sorry

Comment: How can I find externip?

Comment: You can try find it with command `curl myexternalip.com/raw` in cli

Comment: I had to allocate a new elastic IP in aws and edited the sip.conf file to use it but I am confused as there is an entry in sip.conf for externaddr but not externip. Should I change it to externip?

Comment: externaddr is replaced by externip. Change it.

Comment: Sorry, but I never used AWS. And cannot give to you full and correct configuration of asterisk :-(

Comment: Thanks for the advice on externip.

Comment: Ultimately I just changed externaddr to an elastic IP and left nat commented out. Now it doesn't hangup prematurely.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem with audio, but canreinvite is deprecated. directmedia=no and nat=force_rport,comedia are the the correct options to set for the peer.